# Is there a way to run Windows API functions within CUDA kernels?

Tags: windows, api, cuda

I have recently thought to create a Memory Scanner in C++ and I would like to use my CUDA kernels for that. But every time I want to compile my code, I get an Error MSB3721.

So is there a way to call Windows API functions from a CUDA kernel?

Comment: In one word -- No.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot call Windows API from cuda kernel. But maybe, you can use pinnedmemory to access cpu side memory and scan it with some keywords in it from cuda kernels.
For this, you need to constantly feed new memory areas from cpu side while checking if gpu kernels found something or not.

Code could be something like this;

```
    int main()
    {
       Int ScannerID = 0;
       bool result=false;
       byte *h_aPinned;
       int bytes=1000;  //batch size for mem copying

      // allocate and initialize
     cudaMallocHost((void**)&h_aPinned, bytes,cudaHostAllocDefault);

     //do stuff and fill h_aPinned with ram memory

     //constantly check kernel for the results
     do
         kernel<<<x, y>>>(h_aPinned, result, ScannerID);  //(decide x & y for your conditions)

         if (result==false) 
               { 
                   //copy another batch of memory just by filling h_aPinned with it.
               }
     while (result = true)


     return 0;
    }
```

And kernel side could be something like this.

```
    _global__ void kernel(byte* batchmem, bool* result, int* ID) 
{ 
    ID = threadIdx.x;        //for which part of memory return true and calculate batch start point
   //do search with batchmem
   //you can divide search areas on threads
}
```

Comment: What would the point of running memory scans at PCI-e speeds?

Comment: thank you,so like I understood you would load ram memory into the cuda kernels and then process the chunks of memory further ?

Comment: @talonmies it would make my scanning process faster I guess.Do you have a favorite scanning method ?( non CUDA).

Comment: It absolutely would not be faster. The entire idea is nonsensical. Take 30s with a pen and paper and calculate the effective bandwidth and latency and prove that it makes no sense

Comment: @DenisMuhic Yes. that's the idea. But, like talonmies said it would be so slow that doing it with a cpu thread because you have to transfer all the memory to the gpu.

Comment: @talonmies  speed is not the issue here. He didn't ask that. His question can be done with gpu processing in numereus ways, and one of them is up there.

Comment: your `cudaMallocHost` syntax is wrong.  and it certainly appears to me that `result` will always be false.

Comment: So can I ask you, how you would suggest to read memory of a running process ? Would you use ReadProcessMemory or would you map the file's memory and then process that ? I think ReadprocessMemory is a bit slow, though I have tried to not too much avail with std::thread